# How to disable model validation to allow fluent validation checking

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, fluentvalidation, model-validation

I have the following controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ReleaseController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public Task<ReleaseModel> UpdateAsync([FromBody] UpdateReleaseForm form, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _releaseService.UpdateAsync(form, cancellationToken);
}
```

The `form` among other properties has `enum` property `ReleaseStatus`:

```
public class UpdateReleaseForm
{
    // other props omitted for brevity

    public ReleaseStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

I use `FluentValidation` to create a rule for the `Status`:

```
internal sealed class UpdateReleaseFormValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateReleaseForm>
{
    public UpdateReleaseFormValidator()
    {
        // other rules omitted for brevity

        RuleFor(u => u.Status)
            .ReleaseStatusValidation();
    }
}

public static class RuleBuildersExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, ReleaseStatus> ReleaseStatusValidation<T>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, ReleaseStatus> rule)
    {
        return rule.
            IsInEnum()
            .WithMessage(
                string.Format("Status should be one of the following values: `{0}`",
                string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(ReleaseStatus)))));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a wrong `Status` passed in to the action method, I get the error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "status": [
            "Error converting value \"WrongStatus\" to type '...ReleaseStatus'. Path 'Status', line 4, position 28."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|3405bc61-4f67bebc131b8dc8."
}
```

I want to get my custom message defined in validation rule instead.

I tried to use `NullObjectModelValidator` from [disable-validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#disable-validation).

Also I tried this:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
```

But get the following:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Cannot pass null model to Validate.
> (Parameter 'instanceToValidate')

Comment: This isn't really model validation: it's `System.Text.Json` and its [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter) type. It isn't able to parse `WrongStatus` into the `Status` property, so the whole JSON parsing process fails. Here's a link to the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/EnumConverter.cs#L317-L321).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but you could try to make the UpdateReleaseForm form parameter in the UpdateAsync method [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ReleaseController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public Task<ReleaseModel> UpdateAsync([FromBody] UpdateReleaseForm? form, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _releaseService.UpdateAsync(form, cancellationToken);
}
```

Maybe that will allow the parameter to be null.